# How to plot loop variable i on x-axis and local variable in the loop on y-axis using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am using numpy to practice gradient descent on linear regression. Here is my gradient descent process:

```
def batch_gradient_descent(data_points, initial_b, initial_W, lr, iterations):
    b = initial_b
    W = initial_W
    for i in range(iterations): # Calcultes Gradient Descent for n-iterations.
        b, W = gradient_step(b, W, data_points, lr)
        current_cost = cost(b, W, data_points)
        # plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
        # plt.plot(i, current_cost, linewidth=1)
        # plt.xlabel("iteration")
        # plt.ylabel("log(L)")
        # plt.title("log(L) After "+str(i)+"th iteration")

    plt.show()
    return [b, W]
```

I need to use matplotlib to plot in total only **two** figures:

1. x-axis is i, and y-axis is the log(cost) value according to each i.
2. x-axis is i, and y-axis is the curve of **every** element's value in W, which is a 5 * 1 vector. Thus, there will be 5 lines in this figure.

By the way, the total iteration number is 200, which means the value range on x-axis should be 0 - 200.

My original solution is commented in the code, but what it actually plots is many figures, which seem like:
[image]
[image]

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can append them to a list for your `x` and `y`-axis

```
x = []
y = []

def batch_gradient_descent(data_points, initial_b, initial_W, lr, iterations):
    b = initial_b
    W = initial_W
    for i in range(iterations): # Calcultes Gradient Descent for n-iterations.
        b, W = gradient_step(b, W, data_points, lr)
        current_cost = cost(b, W, data_points)
        x.append(i)
        y.append(current_cost)
    return [b, W]
```

then plot it like:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=1)
plt.xlabel("iteration")
plt.ylabel("log(L)")
plt.title("log(L) After " + str(x[-1]) + "th iteration")
plt.show()
```

[image]